# Creating directory with name containing real number in FORTRAN

Tags: fortran, fortran90

In my program I need to store result files for different cases. I have decided to create separate directories to store these result files. To explain the exact situation here is a pseudo code.

```
do i=1,N     ! N cases of my analysis
    U=SPEED(i)
    call write_files(U)     !Create a new directory for this case and Open files (1 = a.csv, 2 = b.csv) to write data
    call postprocess()      !Write data in files (a.csv, b.csv)
    call close_files()      !Close all files (1,2)
end do

subroutine write_files(i)
    !Make directory i
    !Open file a.csv and b.csv with unit 1 & 2
    !Write header information in file a.csv and b.csv
close subroutine
```

I am struggling in converting the real variable U to a character variable so that I can use `call system('mkdir out/' trim(U))` to create separate folders to store my results.

I would also like to mention that my variable U is speed which is like `0.00000, 1.00000, 1.50000` etc. Is there a way I can simplify my directory name so it is like `0,1,1.5` etc.

Hope my explanation is clear. If not let me know, I will try to edit as required.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument of `system` needs to be a string. You therefore have to cast the `real` to a string and concatenate `mkdir out/` with that string. Here is a quick example:

```
module dirs 
contains
  function dirname(number)
    real,intent(in)    :: number
    character(len=6)  :: dirname

    ! Cast the (rounded) number to string using 6 digits and
    ! leading zeros
    write (dirname, '(I6.6)')  nint(number)
    ! This is the same w/o leading zeros  
    !write (dirname, '(I6)')  nint(number)

    ! This is for one digit (no rounding)
    !write (dirname, '(F4.1)')  number
  end function
end module

program dirtest
  use dirs

  call system('mkdir -p out/' // adjustl(trim( dirname(1.) ) ) )
end program
```

Instead of `call system(...)` which is non-standard, you could use the Fortran 2008 statement `execute_command_line` (if your compiler supports it).

```
call execute_command_line ('mkdir -p out/' // adjustl(trim( dirname(1.) ) ) )
```

Comment: The problem with this (v1) is that with `number=1.0` and `number=1.3`, we'd have `dirname` be the same. It might be better to do `nint(number*10.0)` to ensure the difference is there.

Comment: @KyleKanos: I added something similar as a third option... Although this is not rounding, just cutting of. But it would be a simple exercise to combine it with your approach! Thanks for pointing it out...

Comment: @AlexanderVogt: no problem. I was going to write an answer with the method I gave in the comments, but you beat me to the punch.

Comment: Instead of `system` and `execute_command_line` you may consider to use a wrapper around libc's `mkdir` function. For example, by using the [modFileSys](https://bitbucket.org/aradi/modfilesys) library, you could use `call mkdir(adjustl(trim(dirname(1.))), parents=.true.)`. You would also have the possibility to check whether any error happened during the directory creation.

Comment: Is it possible to create an overloaded function `num2str()` (like Matlab) and use that to create directory names. `num2str` should handle all the real number or integer modifications to nice numbers (1.50000 to 1.5) and converting it to char. I don't have any idea how to clean up the number format though.

Comment: I have used your method to create a overloaded function num2str() similar to Matlab. The code can be found [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735007/creating-an-overloaded-function-to-be-used-in-message-logging)