# Fortran 90 create directory syntax error

Tags: io, directory, fortran, system, fortran90

I thought I found out how to create directories in this post

[Creating directory with name containing real number in FORTRAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664939/creating-directory-with-name-containing-real-number-in-fortran)

But when I tried to create a directory in my Fortran 90 program

```
call system('mkdir -p out/test')
```

or

```
call system('mkdir out/test')
```

I don't get any compilation errors or warnings, but I get the following runtime error:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Any idea what is wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try issuing the command directly from the Windows command line before you embedded it into a Fortran program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message I assume you are using Windows. Then, you have to use `\` as a folder separator:

```
call system('mkdir out\test')
```

Also, `-p` (the Unix option to create parent folders) is invalid for Windows (and also not required).