# Open file in specific folder - gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

This is my code:

```
Program Write_in_folder

Implicit none

Integer::B_st
Character(128)::Output
Character(128),parameter::fmt_1='("Output_",i0,".txt")'
Character(128),parameter::fmt_2='(2x,i0)'

Write(*,*)"Enter the number:"
Read(*,*)B_st

Write(Output,trim(adjustl(fmt_1)))B_st

Open(Unit=1,File=Output,Status='Unknown')

    Write(1,trim(adjustl(fmt_2)))B_st

Close(Unit=1,Status='Keep')

Stop
End Program Write_in_folder
```

I want to open file Output in a specific place in my PC. This place is:

```
D:\Put_Output
```

How do I do this?

Comment: If you want to open a file not in the current working directory just use a full/relative path.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that in this code?

Comment: "Output_" => "D:\Put_Output\Output_". Where do you see any problem?

Comment: Put_Output does not exist.Before execution I must create the folder Put_Output to prevent this message but I want to open folder at specific place and in that folder I want to open file Output_ .How to do that?

Comment: You didn't say that! You also haven't shown us any "this message".

Comment: There are multiple questions here about creating directories. This is one of them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664939/creating-directory-with-name-containing-real-number-in-fortran It is about Linux, but windows has the `mkdir` command too. Another ones are in the list of related questions.

Comment: This one is for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24617016/fortran-90-create-directory-syntax-error?lq=1

Comment: Great.Works very well.
Thank you.

Comment: I want to check every time when I start my program does created folder from first time exist.If he exist I do not want to execute 

`Call execute_command_line('mkdir D:\Output\')`

Is there way for doing that?

Comment: Yes, this is possible via the `inquire` statement. But you should probably ask a new question.